# Running a Java TCP server from a WAR file deployed to Tomcat

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, tcp, war

I have a Java-based server which listens on port 12345 for requests over TCP. Once it is compiled to `javanix-server.class`, I invoke it via `$ java javanix-server` and thereafter, whenever the above process is running I can interact with it by running `telnet localhost 12345`.

I would like this server to be deployed as part of an application - what is the simplest way for me to add it to a WAR file and deploy that WAR on Apache Tomcat, such that whenever Tomcat is running with the WAR deployed I can interact with my server via `telnet localhost 12345`?

I have tried this:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>mina-sshd-tomcat</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SSHD</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.sshd.SshServer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
</web-app>
```

Despite the class appearing to start without incident, the ports bound to via the `main` method in `org.apache.sshd.SshServer` are not actually open once Tomcat is running. Running the same `main` method without modification outside of Tomcat (eg, directly on the JVM) works fine.

Comment: Tomcat won't ever execute the main() method. If you implement this as a servlet, then override its init() method and start a thread running your TCP server there. I would use a ServletContextListener instead of a servlet. You need to learn the basics of servlets first.

Comment: Rather than putting your code in a servlet you should put it in ServletContextListener and start your server socket when the ServletContextListener run on server startup.